# How to change the post title to h1

Tags: seo

Here's a quick question: how do you change the post title to be h1 instead of h3 as it is by default? Can it be done from the CMS or from the actual code? Is there a plugin for this? Thanks and let me know if I need to edit my question before downrating!

Comment: This question is entirely **Theme dependent**. What Theme are you using? Also, technically, this is an HTML question, *not* a **WordPress-specific** question.

Comment: The theme is called Ribbed Creative.

Comment: I know the HTML part and that's not the problem. I just don't know WordPress's structure.

Comment: "*I know the HTML part and that's not the problem.*" - Great! Then just change the appropriate HTML tag from `<h3>` to `<h1>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

theme specific it is, maybe look into themes `single.php`, search for title, or a function call of `the_title()`